# Is all run four adds to the tally of number of 4s of a batsman in cricket?

Tags: cricket

When a batsman runs four runs, does it add to the tally of 4s scored by that batsman?

Answer (score 2):

## No.

The tally of "fours" is specifically for scoring of a Boundary Four, not just any play that happens to score four runs.